# How to get Checkbox status?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have following html control in view:

```
  <%= Html.CheckBox("MyStatus", (item.MyStatus>0)?true:false)%>
```

Then I want to get the value for this checkbox: if it is checked, return true, otherwise return false. I try it as below:

```
$("#MyStatus").attr("checked").value
```

but I can't get the right value.

How to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$("#MyStatus").is(":checked");
```

Answer (score 0):

How to check if checkbox is checked using jQuery
http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-check-if-checkbox-is-checked.html